# Using SignalR and Nancyfx on Owin Selfhost || Angular2 on Clientside

Tags: angular, signalr, owin, nancy

I want to use SignalR and Nacyfx on my Service. So I tryed it with Owin Selfhost. I got my SignalR running and I can access it from my Angular2 Client and I can access my Client from SignalR, so everything seems to be fine with SignalR. 
But when im trying to access/recieve Data from Nancy I fail. I cant access my Nancy from my Client.
I'm running my service on a different Port than my website.

Program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = "http://+:2222";

        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SignalR Server running on {0}", url);
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Startup:

```
 class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration() { EnableJSONP = true });
        app.UseNancy();
    }
}
```

Hub, something like this:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    private readonly static ConnectionMapper<string> _mappedConnections = new ConnectionMapper<string>();

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        var user= Context.QueryString["user"];
        _mappedConnections.Add(user, Context.ConnectionId);

        Console.WriteLine("User connected: " + user);
        Console.WriteLine();

        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}
```

So my SignalR is working with this Code.

And my Nancy looks like:

```
class NancyServiceModule : Nancy.NancyModule
{
    private DatabaseAccess _dbAccess = new DatabaseAccess();
    public NancyServiceModule() : base("/nancy/"){

        Get["/accessible"] = parameters =>
        {
            return new Response
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
            };
        };
    }
}
```

On Clientside I tryed to access Nancy with something like this:

```
export class DatabaseService {

constructor(
    private _http: Http
    ) {}

 getMachines(): Observable<Response> {

    return this._http.get('http://localhost:2222/nancy/accessible');
    //also tryed Hardcoded IP instead of localhost
    }
}
```

I can't figure out if I'm just accessing nacy wrong from my Client or if I got some errors on Serverside. (Webpage is running on Port:3000 at the moment)

In case you nedd more informations or more Code just ask, but i hope i got the most important things.

Would be great if some of you could help me with this problem!

**Update**

When accessing nancy through browser adress bar nancy is showing 404 Error (also showing nancy tabicon). So in a way its working but i cant access it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After one full week of desperation i solved this Problem.

I feel a litle bit dumb because the error occured because my module was not `Public` 
so

```
public class NancyServiceModule : Nancy.NancyModule
{
....
```

solved it.